# How to plot a line graph of an array from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, weather

I have a dataframe, `test`, that contains winter temperatures since 1951 for a city. I want to plot the temperatures contained in the column called `p95_annual` but when I try to do that using `plt.plot(test.p95_annual.values)` I get the following:
[image]
Here's what test, wintermean, and test.wintermean.values looks like:
[image]
How can I plot this temperature data?

Comment: Can you provide your data as code? `test["p95_annual"].to_dict()`? What does each row of the `p95_annual` values represent?

Comment: Here's what that ouputs: {124: '[ 5  0  1  1  0  1  0  5  1  0  5  1  1  2  1  4  6  0  0  7  4  7  7 11\n  1  1  5  5  2  2 14  2  9  8  8 11  2  9 24 11  5  7  8  8  7 12  7  0\n  3 11 10  9  4  2  4 14 12  6  9  5  5  9 18 12 18 23 25 22 27 14]'} . The `p95_annual` values represent the numbr of days in each year above a threshold

Comment: What does each row in that represent? What should your output graph look like? The first two "rows" have 24 numbers and the last has only 22

Comment: There shouldn't be any rows. It should just be 70 values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one single row in your DataFrame which has a string. You need to parse the individual values from this string before plotting it:

```
data = list(map(int, test.at[124,"p95_annual"][1:-1].split()))

>>> plt.plot(data)
```

[image]